# How can I put header parameter in a Url?

Tags: rest, web, url

I want to get data from API. So first I want to get Json response from the browser. I Usually do it by specifying a query to pass the API key. But this time the API key is passed using header parameter instead of a query. How can I pass the API into a header parameter?

This is the base Url

> "https://api-nba-v1.p.rapidapi.com"

This is the header parameter:

> x-rapidapi-key

Comment: Which library are you using for API calls? Retrofit, Volley or some other. If you are trying to get response in browser then remove android tag from your question and add web tag in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to issue this request first using some rest client like postman or insomnia.

Comment: I want to get a json response. So first I have to have an authorization by passing the API key.

Comment: You can also run this request first to obtain the authorization and after that pass it in the proper field. The point is that if you to see the json output it would be easier for you to use a proper rest client than trying to issue the calls in your browser, you could also do that but you will need an extension or something in order to do so.